# Check/uncheck checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What would be the best way to check/uncheck another checkbox in the following example:

```
<label title="">NSK<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="eph-ds[<?php echo $eph['eph_id']; ?>][]" value="NSK" />
</label>
<label title="">F<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="eph-ds[<?php echo $eph['eph_id']; ?>][]" value="F" />
</label>
<label title="">PR<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="eph-ds[<?php echo $eph['eph_id']; ?>][]" value="PR" />
</label>
<label title="">DPH<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="eph-ds[<?php echo $eph['eph_id']; ?>][]" value="DPH" />
</label>
```

If "NSK" is checked, uncheck "PR". If "PR" is checked, uncheck "F". If "DPH" is checked, uncheck all.

Comment: Are you recreating radio buttons with checkboxes?

Comment: It looks like he's going for a very specific set of rules not suitable to radiobuttons.

Comment: Yes, exactly as said by Will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target specific elements with jQuery using the attribute selector:

```
$(":checkbox[value=PR]")
```

For example, the above targets the checkbox with `PR` as the value. Now, you can link these to a change function:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    var current = this.value;
    if (current == "PR") {
        $(":checkbox[value=F]").prop("checked", false);
    } 
    //so on and so forth
});
```

`.prop` is used to check / uncheck a checkbox. You can go through and customize the above to your set of rules.

Comment: :radio = :checkbox and it is working nicely.

Comment: @Adrian -- Woops :) glad it worked!